# Issues with Win32 document read from Flask

Tags: python, pywin32, win32com

When attempting to `.read()` the `<FileStorage: 'Report.docx' ('application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document')>` object with `word.Documents.Open(document.read())` the below error message triggers. Is there something I am missing?

**Error Message:** `pywintypes.com_error: (-2147352571, 'Type mismatch.', None, 1)`

```
@app.route('/home', methods=['GET','POST'])
def home():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        document = request.files['document']
        document_name = request.files['document'].filename

        word = win32.gencache.EnsureDispatch('Word.Application')
        word.Visible = False 

        comments = []
        doc = word.Documents.Open(document.read())
        doc.Activate()
        active_doc = word.ActiveDocument
```

Comment: maybe first write it as normal file and check what you get in file. Maybe you send it in wrong way or you send wrong file. And this may need to use `try/catch` to catch error when user send ie. image instead of word file.

Comment: I have tried to extract the document, it exports correctly as docx. I have also tried to run a blank docx file through the `.Open()` and it works. For some reason though, when I call it via Flask through the `request` function, it is not working.

Comment: maybe check what you get with `document.read()`

Comment: I don't use windows to check it but maybe `Open()` can't work directly with data but it needs filename or file-like object - ie, `word.Documents.Open(document)` without `.read()` or `word.Documents.Open( io.BytesIO(document.read()) )`

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.documents.open

The Open() function expects a string file path as the first parameter. I am pretty sure it won't accept a stream. Maybe you'll have to save the stream to a file, and then Open() that?